# Python find index of all dates between two dates

Tags: datetime, numpy

I am trying to implement equivalent of `numpy.where` for dates as follows:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td, datetime
d1 = datetime.strptime('1/1/1995', "%m/%d/%Y")
d2 = datetime.strptime('12/31/2015', "%m/%d/%Y")

AllDays = []
while(d1<=d2):
    AllDays.append(d1)
    d1 = d1 + td(days=1)

validDate = AllDays
trainStDt = '1/1/1995'
trainEnDt = '12/31/2013'
testStDt = '1/1/2014'
testEnDt = '12/31/2015'

indTrain = (validDate >= datetime.strptime(trainStDt,'%m/%d/%Y')) & (validDate <=
                                                                           datetime.strptime(trainEnDt,'%m/%d/%Y'))
indTest = (validDate >= datetime.strptime(testStDt,'%m/%d/%Y')) & (validDate <=
                                                                          datetime.strptime(testEnDt,'%m/%d/%Y'))
trainDates = validDate[indTrain]
testDates = validDate[indTest]

print trainDates[0]
print trainDates[-1:]
print testDates[0]
print testDates[-1:]
```

However:
(1) indTrain doesn't work as it is trying to compare list to datetime
(2) my solution is to loop through each element of validDates

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn your list into an array. Add `import numpy as np` to the top of your script, and after your `while` loop, add:

```
AllDays = np.array(AllDays)
```